# Error: redefinition of default parameter : parameter 3 but not redefining?

Tags: c++, class, textures, sdl

As far as I can see the code for this class works yet it will not compile and is throwing the error mentioned in the title. Below is the header file.

This is using the SDL standard libraries.

texture2D.h

```
#ifndef TEXTURE2D_H
#define TEXTURE2D_H

#include <SDL.h>
#include <string>
#include "Commons.h"

using namespace::std;

class Texture2D
{
    SDL_Renderer* mRenderer;
    SDL_Texture* mTexture;

    int mWidth;
    int mHeight;

public:
    Texture2D(SDL_Renderer* renderer);
    ~Texture2D();

    bool LoadFromFile(string path);
    void Free();
    void Render(Vector2D newPosition, SDL_RendererFlip flip, double angle = 0.0f);

    int GetWidth() { return mWidth; }
    int GetHeight() { return mHeight; }
};

#endif
```

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Comment: You're probably re-defining it in the member function definition.

Comment: Please show the offending method definition, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine your definition of Render looks like this

In .cpp

```
  void Texture2D::Render(Vector2D newPosition, SDL_RendererFlip flip, double angle = 0.0f)
  {
     ...
  }
```

When it should be

```
  void Texture2D::Render(Vector2D newPosition, SDL_RendererFlip flip, double angle )
  {
     ...
  }
```

You only supply the default value in the declaration ( normally .h )

Comment: Please ask for clarification in comments. It is not worth posting guesses for unclear questions.

Comment: Sorry, not yet fully aware of stack overflow etiquette.

Comment: Good guess. But you've posted two function *declarations*. This is a bit confusing. Also, you're missing the class scope.

Comment: @Laszlo, it seemed to me a very high chance that this was the error, based on the info originally posted by OP. Maybe you missed the error message in the title?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: high chance or not, unclear question is unclear. You may may experience quite a bit of surprise on this site following unclear questions and consequences. I have done so. I am much more careful after those.